# Why @ref in Blazor server-side does not render correctly after removed items?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

Here is my code in front-end:

```
    @page "/"
    @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
    
    <ul>
        @foreach (TestClass i in TestList)
        {
            if (i.Count != 0)
            {
            <li>
                <button @onclick="() => RemoveVoid(i)" style="display:inline-block">Remove</button>
                <p @ref="@i.Reference" style="display:inline-block">@(string.Format("{0}×{1}", @i.Name, i.Count))</p>
                <button @onclick="() => AddVoid(i)" style="display:inline-block">Add</button>
            </li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
    
    @code{
        public class TestClass
        {
            public string Name;                
            public int Count=1;
            public ElementReference Reference;
    }
    List<TestClass> TestList = new List<TestClass>()
{
        new TestClass(){ Name="Apple" },
            new TestClass(){ Name="Pear" },
            new TestClass(){ Name="Banana" },
            new TestClass(){ Name="Orange" },
            new TestClass(){ Name="Melon" }
    };
    void AddVoid(TestClass i)
    {
        i.Count++;
        StateHasChanged();
        JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("AppFunctions.Test", i.Reference);
    }
    void RemoveVoid(TestClass i)
    {
        i.Count--;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

And here is the code in JS:

```
window.AppFunctions = {   
    Test: function (o) {
        o.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        setTimeout(function () {
            o.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }, 2000);
    }    
};
```

Now it looks like this:
[image]

Firstly, we remove the Pear to 0.

And then we add the Banana to 2.

[image]

Now you will find the highlight is on the Orange but not on the Banana correctly.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Why do you use JavaScript for thios?  Seems like it would be easy to do in C#.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Actually I need to get the left and top of the element to achieve animation. I want to make the example easier by replacing it with a highlight effect.

Comment: It has got nothing to do with the use of JS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use @key to control the preservation of elements and components
> When rendering a list of elements or components and the elements or components subsequently change, Blazor's diffing algorithm must decide which of the previous elements or components can be retained and how model objects should map to them. Normally, this process is automatic and can be ignored, but there are cases where you may want to control the process.

Your issue is solved by using the @key attribute like this:

```
<p @key="@i" @ref="@i.Reference" style="display:inline-block">@(string.Format("{0}×{1}", @i.Name, i.Count))</p>
```

Note: Calling the StateHasChanged method is not necessary...

Why don't you remove TestClass objects from the list with the Remove method ?

Comment: Would you please tell me why StateHasChanged is not necessary. I always consider I should use the StateHasChanged when the UI needs to be updated.

Comment: The system is used for buying fruits. It is more efficient to use a count property in the element than add so much list element to record the fruit count.

Comment: The StateHasChanged  method is automatically called whenever a UI event such as click or change or input, etc. is triggered. In past phases of the development of Blazor you had to add it manually though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling me about this.